# Email service preventing email workflow to fire

Tags: email, workflow, apex-email-service

I noticed that when I enabled a custom email service handler, any of the email message workflow rules I created prior were not being hit. In other words, is it
true that an email service will override any workflows or processes on the email message object? I tested this in sandbox, and it seemed to be consistent with this hypothesis. Any SF documentation that states this?

Thanks,

Comment: A custom Apex email service handler does not necessarily create or interact with the standard EmailMessage object that is present when Enhanced Email is enabled. If your Apex email service handler is inserting new EmailMessage records, I would expect triggers and workflow to fire. Is that what you're seeing? Please edit your question to specify in more detail what the email service handler does and what expected behavior you're not seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My email service handler does not insert an email message -but instead uses the inbound message to create other objects such as cases or chatter posts. Specifically, I had an email workflow such that inbound email messages would update the case status that the email is associated to. However, that workflow doesn't seem to fire when the service handler is enabled.

Comment: Right, so a workflow acts on an SObject. In your case, an EmailMessage. Emails that are handled by standard Email-to-Case functionality are records of this SObject. An email that gets processed by an Apex Email Service is not an SObject at all - it's an instance of the Messaging.InboundEmail class, and so won't trigger your workflow. You could **create** EmailMessage records in your Apex handler, and if they meet your criteria, they would trigger the workflow.